# how can i apply limit to recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

i want apply limit to recyclerview and only show 5 result in it and in the end of the list show a button for go to another place?!

my code in below;

adapter codes:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.Holder> {

ArrayList<Products> ProductsList;
Context context;

public ProductAdapter(ArrayList<Products> productsList, Context context) {
    ProductsList = productsList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_horizental, parent, false);
    return new Holder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {

    Products products = ProductsList.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(products.getName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(products.getPrice());
    Picasso.get().load(Config.ip_value + "/images/" + products.getPhoto()).into(holder.imgV);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ProductsList.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtPrice;
    ImageView imgV;

    public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowTxtProductName);
        txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowTxtPrice);
        imgV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowImgProduct);
    }
}
}
```

i have some codes in main fragment but i dont think its necessary to put in this place but if you want to see them comment and i will put all in update text

thanks

Comment: Can you Add Fragment  Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either slice the `list` to contain only `5` items before passing it to `RecyclerView` or just change `getItemCount` method in `Adapter` to return `5`

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ProductsList.size() > 5 ? 5 : ProductsList.size();
}
```

Comment: when i change getItemCount() i got an error and app carash

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it saves from `IOB` exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can set limit as by using getItemCount() as

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 5;
}
```

by another place if u mean to other activity or fragment, then place
the button at the end of your recyclerview layout in your xml file.

for e.g : if using RelativeLayout,

```
                  <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"/>
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Next"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview"
                            android:id="@+id/btn_next"/>
                        
                    </RelativeLayout>
```

then on button click you can call the intent or similar to go to your page

Comment: i want put button in end of scrolling (i have horizontal recycler view) ?!

Comment: <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="100dp"> <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/rc_asteroids"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="200dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"/> <Button android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/> </LinearLayout> </HorizontalScrollView>

Answer (score 0):

You can set limit query in your ProductsList API.
if you are using retrofit2

you can define limit parametr in your API interface, if that option has in your backend server,

```
@GET("products")
Call<Products> getProducts(@Query("limit") int limit);
```

and define method in your activity class where you pass setAdapter, like below

```
   public void getProducts(int limit){

    Call<Products> call = yourAPI.getProducts(limit);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Products>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Products> call, Response<Products> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                ArrayList<Products> products = response.body();
                if (products == null) products = new ArrayList<>();
                productsAdapter.setData(products); // setData needs to be defined in your adapter

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Products> call, Throwable t) {
            if(t.getMessage() != null) Log.e("ErrorTag", t.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "Server Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });
```

Don't forget to define new method called setData,

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Products> productsList) {
    this.ProductsList.addAll(productsList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
};
```

And to get other 5 products I don't advise you to create next or prev button,
better add code below in your onBindViewHolder method of your adapter to make load another 5 more products when user scrolls to the last item,

```
   if (position == (ProductsList.size() - 1)){
        if (context instanceof YourActivity){
            YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) context;
            activity.getProducts(ProductsList.size());
        }
    }
```